# Get the path with query string on the current http request in PHP

Tags: php, url

I need to get the path with query string from the URL of the current request. For example, if the current URL is:

```
"http://www.example.com/example/test/hi.php?randomvariable=1"
```

I would want this:

```
"/example/test/hi.php?randomvariable=1"
```

Comment: You are asking for both the path and the query string together, but people who are googling for how to just find the path will end up here.  Can you change the title to be "Get current URL path with query string in PHP"?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> #### `'REQUEST_URI'`
>
> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, `'/index.html'`.

Answer (score 50):

it should be :

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Take a look at : [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url)

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
function current_url()
{
    $url      = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $validURL = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $url);
    return $validURL;
}
//echo "page URL is : ".current_url();

$offer_url = current_url();

?>



<?php

if ($offer_url == "checking url name") {
?> <p> hi this is manip5595 </p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You might offer some explanation of what this does that the one-liner in the accepted answer doesn't.