# How to Identify URL of page and perform an action based on the URL

Tags: php

I have created a custom header (header.php) and one of the components in it is the flag representing the langauge of the site.

What I am looking to do is,
IF the current webpage URL is "www.abcde.com/en" then Do X, where X will be the  for the English Flag.
If Else, then Do Y, where Y is to load  for the Chinese flag.

I do not want to create seperate header files as the only difference is this.

Looking forward to your expert advice :)

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` extract 'en'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URL path in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198790/get-current-url-path-in-php)

Comment: Thank you  Smith
Can you please get me the full query to write as am zero on PHP

Basically i have all my pages loading under www.abcde.com/en/asd/asd/asd/sad/ or
www.abcde.com/cn/asd/asd/asd/asd/

So the comparision is only for first few charachters of the URL.. which is upto "www.abcde.com/en"

1. How to get this part
2. How to code the rest to do what i want...IE : If value is true, then Do X.. If value is false then do Y

Comment: this is not a free coding service, so no I'm not wring your php for you. either start learning, or hire some one